# How is Comparative Advantage a superset of Absolute Advantage?

Tags: international-trade, comparative-advantage

[Source](http://internationalecon.com/Trade/Tch40/T40-0.php): 'The Theory of Comparative Advantage - Overview', [Prof Steven M. Suranovic](http://economics.columbian.gwu.edu/steven-m-suranovic)

> Advantageous trade based on comparative advantage, then, covers a larger set of circumstances while still including the case of absolute advantage and hence is a more general theory.

Please explain this? What's the intuition, which I prefer over a formal proof?

Comment: Since you've already posted a question asking for the intuition behind comparative advantage, maybe you should wait for an answer before posting additional questions that ask again, in essence for the intuition behind comparative advantage.

Comment: @tohster How are these duplicates? They don't seem so.

Comment: They're duplicates because you are spamming the site asking for an intuitive understanding about comparative advantage from 4 different angles while adducing little to show that you have done any research to answer your own questions.  This results in 4x the demand for the community's time to help you understand a principle intuitively, which comes at the cost of folks answering questions from other more researched questioners. You may certainly claim that the questions are distinct, but before you argue that you may want to look at the down votes to assess what others think of this approach.

Comment: Re: "how to improve the questions": Simple. Include in the questions some thoughts on a) what _you_ think could be the intuition and/or b) why your tentative answer is unsatisfactory to you -which in turn validates your asking for help here.